# Error console says "function not defined"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

The error console shows the following error:

> Error: review is not defined
>   Source File: http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=information/savingsaccount
>   Line: 1

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function review(id) {
$.ajax({
alert(id);
        text = $.trim($("#text").val());
        name = $.trim($("#name").val());
        rating = $.trim($("#rating").val());

        url = "savingsreview.php";
        data = "name="+name+"&text="+text+"&rating="+rating;
        result  = $.ajax({
              url: url,
              global: false,
              type: "GET",
              data: data,
              async:false,
              beforeSend: function(){
              },
           }
        ).responseText;
        alert(result);
    }
}); 
}

</script>
<div style="width:540px;" align="center"><a id="displayText"     
href="javascript:toggle(<?php echo $id;?>);">Review & Read Reviews</a></div>
<span id="toggleText<?php echo $id;?>"  style="display: none">


<div class="content">


<label><b>Your Name</b></label> : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />

<label><b>Your Review</b></label> :<textarea name="text" id="text"  rows="3">  </textarea> 

<label><b>Rating</b></label>
    <input id="rating" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" style="margin: 0;" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" style="margin: 0;" />
    &nbsp;

 <a onclick="review(<?php echo $id;?>);" class="button"><span>Submit</span></a></td>

</span>


Can anyone help me solve this??
```

Comment: Posting a localhost address doesn't help us, since it's (well) a localhost, ie. local to the machine you're running the code on. If you want us to see what's happening you need to provide a publicly accessible URL.

Comment: Is it a typo that the function starts with `$.ajax({`?

Comment: your syntax is wrong. you have object {} as a parameter in .ajax function. In object you can declare only key-value

Comment: You seem to be using an Ajax call inside an Ajax call. That's not correct.. The answer of @genesis is.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
function review(id) {

    alert(id);
    var text = $.trim($("#text").val());
    var name = $.trim($("#name").val());
    var rating = $.trim($("#rating").val());

    var url = "savingsreview.php";
    var data = "name=" + name + "&text=" + text + "&rating=" + rating;
    var result = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        global: false,
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function() {},
    }).responseText;
    alert(result);


}
```

there was some garbage so I removed it and it should work (like `$.ajax()` just after `function review(id) {`)

Comment: You're falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I was not trying to optimalize his code, but just make it able to run it. I removed syntax error, not horrors

Answer (score 2):

The function definition of `review` is hideously broken.

You start out by calling `$.ajax` and passing it what looks like a object literal until you get to the first line inside it, at which point you appear to be trying to write a function.

I suggest making use of [jslint](http://jslint.com)

Comment: I'd guess the `alert ...` parts inside the ajax call, because of being syntactically wrong, are breaking the `review` function as a whole, and thus the function is `not defined` on the later call.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your code to freeze while waiting on the response (which it will if you use async false), you should pass in a success handler which will be called once the response is received, something like:

```
function sendAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        // arguments
    },getResponse);
}

function getResponse(response) {
    // deal with what came back
}
```